# Find subset of size k such that the minimum distance between values is maximum

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose i have an array which contain `n` integers .
How to find subset of size `k` such that the `minimum` distance between all pairs of integers in the subset is `maximized` , i mean they are at farthest distance .

example : array `a[]={1,2,6,7,10}` and `k=3` ,
`subset = {1,6,10}` , the minimum distance is `4` between 10 and 6 .
**Wrong subsets** :
`{1,7,10}` , minimum distance is `3`
`{1,2,6}` , minimum distance is `1`

I came up with a solution  :

1) sort array
2) select a[0] , now find ceil(a[0]+ `x`) = Y in array ....and then  ceil(Y+ `x`) and so on `k-1` times , also kth element will be `a[n-1]`

To find `x` :
`dp[i,j]` be the `x` for selecting j elements from first i elements .
Finally we want `dp[n][k]` which is `x`

But i am facing problem in finding `x` .

> dp[i,j] = max( min( dp[k,j-1], dp[i]-A[k] ) )
>                   over   k=1 to i-1  , i=2 to n , j=2 to i
>
> dp[i][1] = 0  over i = 1 to n

**EDIT** : I want to correct the **dynamic programming** solution , though i know x can be found out by binary searching over x .

**UPDATE 2** :  I have updated the code , but still not getting correct solution . Please point the error .
code : http://ideone.com/J5vvR9

**UPDATE 3** : Thanks @Gassa , @Niklas B. and @Fallen for your answers !.

Comment: If you want to do it with dynamic programming only, then you'll need another parameter `x` I believe. Because the state would be, current index(i), number of elements picked so far(j) and the minimum distance so far(x).

Comment: Please show us the problem you have with that recurrence. The formula also has obvious typos in them, please correct those. I think you assume a sorted array so please state that

Comment: Yeah, that seems feasible (yet inefficient compared to a binary search, but that's for you to judge). Define the abstract DP states as (i, j, k, x): after sorting, we looked over the first i values, picked j of them, the last picked one was k, and the minimal distance so far is x. These states correspond to boolean values (is the state reachable or not). From here, we can note certain monotonicity: e.g. if (i, j, k, x) is reachable, then (i, j, k, x+1) is too, as is (i, j-1, j, x). So you can make a DP doing (i, j, k) -> min x, or another doing (i, k, x) -> max k, or otherwise.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like we won't be able to drop any of (i, j, k, x) from the state while preserving correctness.

Comment: So, regarding your DP attempt: I think k is a necessary part of a subproblem, you can't just loop over it when you do DP transitions.

Comment: @Gassa we could define state (i, j) so that i was certainly picked. This yields an O(nk) algo (which is what OP tried I suppose)

Comment: @Gassa: We can loop over k, can't we?

Comment: @Fallen: My understanding is that we need to know the position of the _last_ selected element in the array (k in my comments). We loop over the position of the _next_ element we pick (k in the question). Sorry, my bad, they are now named the same. Otherwise, we don't know what is the value A[k2] - A[k1] we just added to the set of differences.

Comment: @NiklasB. O(nk)? How will we define the minimum distance so far? Say for an array ` 1 2 3 4 5` we can reach state `[3][2)` in 2 different ways taking the last taken item, 3 , `(1, 3)`, `(2,3)` and these two will result different. How to handle this?

Comment: @Niklas B.: Yeah, that's what I missed. Right you are.

Comment: @Fallen you store the max in in dp(i, j)? You know what you picked last  and the array is sorted, so you know what the nearest element is

Comment: @Niklas B.: No, it's the minimum x, not maximum. And so there's a bug in initialization (see my other answer).

Comment: @Gassa well dp(i, j) is the maximized distance when i is picked and j-1 other elements before j. That's what I meant :)

Comment: @Niklas B.: Alright. (1) It is maximized in the sense that we pick the optimal k on each step. (2) After picking k, we store the minimum of what we already accounted for (dp[k,j-1]) and the new difference (A[i]-A[k]). Yeah, there's another bug there, going to mention it in the answer.

Comment: Whew. Now everything makes sense for me. Thanks all =)

Comment: @Fallen Oh I just realized that probably you meant how to do compute dp(i,j) can be computed fast. It's tricky but I think it can be done. Let `b[i,j]` be the smallest k such that `dp[k,j-1] >= a[i] - a[k]`. Then we can remove the `min` from the recurrence: `dp[i,j] = max(max_{k=1 to b[i,j]-1}(a[i]-a[k]), max_{k=b[i,j] to i-1}(dp[k,j-1]))` Both LHS and RHS of the max are easy to compute using prefix and range minima. `b[i,j]` is monotone in `i`, so it's easy to find in amortized O(1). The only problem is the range minimum, RMQ can be done in O(n) with O(1) query, but it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @Niklas B.: I didn't exactly understand what's going on, but that can not be right without a minimum operation somewhere. Suppose you already picked something with distance 1 and took that into account in dp[k,j-1]. Now you have distance a[i]-a[k] = 10. The answer for dp[i,j] is 1: we already have picked something worse than 10 in the subproblem, it does not matter that the current distance is 10.

Comment: @Gassa: I just removed the min by splitting it into the two cases where one or the other side is smaller (although I now realize that I did it the wrong way round). It's not that it's no longer there. It's also more of a mind experiment because noone in their right mind would want to implement a linear-time RMQ preprocessing algorithm. I just realized that we can replace the RMQ with a monotonic deque, so that might be a viable option ;) It is quite likely that I made a mistake somewhere, so no guarantees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base should be:

```
dp[i][1] = INFINITY for i = 1 to n
```

The reason being that [minimum of an empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Extended_real_numbers) is positive infinity.

In practice, any integer larger than the maximum possible `a[i] - a[j]` for some `i` and `j` will suffice as an `INFINITY` constant.

Additionally, the correct transition would be:

```
dp[i,j] = max{for k=1 to i-1} (min(dp[k,j-1], a[i]-a[k]))
```

Comment: sorry , but i am not able to still get the correct answer , my code is here http://ideone.com/J5vvR9 .

Comment: @aseem: For "impossible" cases you have to use negative infinity. For example in your program dp[1,2] = infinity and you use that as a subresult

Comment: 1. Your `o = -1;` initialization line should be inside both loops. 2. Your i and j loop boundaries don't work right. Perhaps the upper triangle being -1'd is necessary as part of the DP base, as @Niklas B. stated. 3. [Here](http://ideone.com/npT9wK) is a corrected version.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need in *finding* `x` if time allows to *search* for possible values of `x`. Just add the outer loop which will be a binary search on the answer (that is, the minimum distance, let us call it `x`).

Once `x` is fixed, you can greedily pick values starting from `a[0]`. The next selected value will be such `a[i]` that `i` is minimal and `a[i] - a[0] >= x`. The third one will be `a[j]` such that `j` is minimal and `a[j] - a[i] >= x`, and so on. If you are able to pick at least `k` values in this fashion, the actual answer is at least the current `x`; if not, the answer is less than `x`.

The total running time will be O (n log (C)) where C is the total number of possible values in the array. Say, if the integers in the array are from 0 to 1000000, C will be 1000001 and log (C) (rounded up) will be 20. First, you try `x = 500000`; if it fails, you are left with the range [0; 500000) for the answer; if not, with the range [500000; 1000000], etc.

Comment: please explain how to improve DP solution

Comment: @NiklasB.: please observe it carefully , because it is correct as far as logic is concerned , i am not able to find base cases .

Comment: @aseem so the array is sorted? Please include this kind of information in the question

Comment: @NiklasB.: yes array is sorted .

Answer (score 1):

Do a binary search over value of X. Then for each such x, write a DP/Greedy function that checks if there's an array with result(maximal distance between elements) more than or equal to X.

**Correctness:** If for any X, we can have M elements, such that minimum distance between them is greater than or equal to X, then for every x, x < X, at least this same array will server as result. And for any X, if there's no M elements, such that the minimum distance between the elements is greater than or equal to X, then for no x, x > X, M such elements are available. So we can binary search on X.

Comment: please explain how to improve upon the DP solution

Comment: @aseem: The best and straight forward solution for this problem is the one provided by Gassa. And I don't think there's a more efficient DP solution to this one, at least I don't know.