# How to get the maximum distance of all subsets in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, subset, distance

I had an interview question as below:

Suppose we have a line and M points in this line. If we define the distance of a subset of points which has N (N <= M) points to be the minimum distance of the distance between of each pair of point, write a algorithm to find the maximum distance of all subsets, each one has N points...

By this I mean, if we have an array {1,2,10}, and N=2, then the subset with the maximum distance should be {1,10}. My first thought was to get all the combinations of subset and calculate the distance of each one, but the interviewer didn't like it because it would take too much time. Does anyone have a time efficient idea?

Comment: looks duplicate of [Subset Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424885/find-subset-of-size-k-such-that-the-minimum-distance-between-values-is-maximum)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the array, and find the 1st element(Smallest) and M will always be the last element (largest), So subset will always be the {smallest,Largest}.

Comment: That only works for the edge case when N = 1. Consider the example where N = 2, but with input `{1, 10, 2}` instead.

Comment: consider n is also an input, your approach only works when N=2

Answer (score 0):

Having things arranged along a line is often a tip-off that dynamic programming will work.

Work from left to right. At each point in the line work out, for k = 1..N the set of points of size k amongst those seen so far that has the largest minimum distance. You can work out the the answers for one point in the line from the answers you have already worked out for points to its left. To find the answer for k points, consider each point to its left and find min(minimum distance for k-1 points at that point, distance from current point to that point). Then take the maximum of these possible values.