# Pick numbers to maximize interval

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array that contains a number from 0 to 999 in strictly increasing order.

For example

```
int[] array = {0, 24, 55, 124, 200, 259, 400, 503, 666, 797};
```

What I have to do is implement a function that picks N numbers so that the minimum value of distances between those picked numbers is maximized.

For example, if N is 3, then the picked numbers are 0, 400, 797 and the intervals are 400 and 397; so the return value is 397 (which should be maximized). If we pick other sets of numbers, then the return value would be less than (or equal to) 397.

I'd like to implement it using recursion, but I'm having a hard time coding it. Would you like to help me?

Comment: what is the limit on $n$ ? what complexity do you expect ? what did you try ?

Comment: This problem is already solved. See the following thread [Find subset of size k such that the minimum distance between values is maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424885/find-subset-of-size-k-such-that-the-minimum-distance-between-values-is-maximum)

Comment: If N is 3 then you have to pick the first element, the last one and the one that is closest to the middle point, this a binary search so it is O(log(n).
For higher N there might be something similar.

Comment: (Please improve the title) `Would you like to help me?` Some might be more inclined if you showed what you tried (here: what the idea is that you didn't succeed in coding, yet). `I'd like to implement it using recursion` So what are the basic cases, and how do you reduce a big problem instance to smaller ones, and how do you put together so solution to the big instance form "the small solutions"? (And I'm not getting _23thMay_: Is it a pun?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved using [dynamic programing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

If we define `s[c][p]` to be the solution when picking `c` numbers and the last chosen number has index `p` in the input array.

We can then calculate `s[c][p]` as `max for i=0..p of max(s[c-1][p-i], array[p] - array[p-i])`

At the beginning following states: `s[1][0..n]`, where `n` is the length of the input array, should have value `0`.

Having `s[1][0..n]` we can now easily calculate `s[2][0..n]`, using given formula.
Having `s[2][0..n]` we can now easily calculate `s[3][0..n]`.
And so on ...

The solution to the entire problem would be `max s[N][N-1..n]` where `n` is the length of the input array and `N` is number of numbers to choose.

The time complexity of this solution is `O(N*n^2)`.
**Explanation:** We calculate values for `s[0..N][0..n]` where each calculation has time complexity of `O(n)`.

The memory complexity of this solution is `O(n)`.
**Explanation:** to calculate `s[c][0..n]` you only need `s[c-1][0..n]` so only `2*n` of the memory is actually needed in every point in time.

EDIT: You can use recursion to implement described algorithm, using programming technique called memoization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).